# From a filepath string, get only the directory path of the parent directory

Tags: php, string, directory, path

so I am trying to learn some string functions in PHP and came across a scenario I cannot figure out. I want to take a string like such: `/var/www/html` and remove everything after the last forward slash (including the forward slash) so I end up with `/var/www`

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`dirname`](http://www.php.net/dirname). It may handle special cases for you that you may not have anticipated if you went with a string manipulation route.

Comment: +1, this is probably a better solution than mine if it's actually for file paths.

Comment: Be aware that it will treat / and \ as the same, which will fail on a unix system that has a \ in a file name

Comment: @Petah: That's true, but if you have to integrate with Windows, it might even be preferable.

Comment: Great to know! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$str = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '/') - 1);
```

...but see [icktoofay's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210591/php-string-help/6210603#6210603) if you're only planning on using this to handle file paths.

Comment: `dirname` is not limited to file paths